# How to set a installation path in composer.phar for a certain required package?

Tags: php, composer-php, ckeditor, typo3-8.x, ckeditor4.x

I've set up a require list for TYPO3 CMS 8 and want to add the ck editor for general usage (also in extensions).

```
...

"require": {
    "helhum/typo3-console": "^4.9.3 || ^5.2",
    "typo3/cms-about": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-belog": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-beuser": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-context-help": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-documentation": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-felogin": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-form": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-func": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-impexp": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-info": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-info-pagetsconfig": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-setup": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-sys-note": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-t3editor": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-tstemplate": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-viewpage": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-wizard-crpages": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3/cms-wizard-sortpages": "^8.7.10",
    "typo3-ter/extension-builder": "^8.10.2",
    "typo3-ter/realurl": "^2.4.0",
    "ckeditor/ckeditor": "4.*"
},

...

"extra": {
        "typo3/cms": {
            "web-dir": "public"
        },
        "helhum/typo3-console": {
            "comment": "This option is not needed ay more for helhum/typo3-console 5.x",
            "install-extension-dummy": false
        }
},

...
```

How can I change the installation path of the ckeditor package to for example to the `/public/vendor/` path instead of the general `/vendor` one? I need this because my Apache directly roots into the `/public` folder.

Comment: The easiest way is to use this plugin : https://github.com/slowprog/CopyFile, you can copy files from vendor to public after install / update.

Comment: @VincentDecaux Mhh instead of that I also can create a softlink the vendor/ckeditor folder, can't I?

Comment: Yes it's another good way I think, I use symlinks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a symbolic link to put `vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor` in my TYPO3 CMS extension like `resources/public/ckeditor`.

Answer (score -2):

why not to put all vendors to public/vendor?

**vendor-dir**

Defaults to vendor. You can install dependencies into a different
directory if you want to. $HOME and ~ will be replaced by your home
directory's path in vendor-dir and all *-dir options below.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir

Comment: TYPO3 CMS installed via composer separates that by default.